# How to select those ids where certain field takes 2 different values in SQL?

Tags: sql, string-aggregation

The search result table:

```
date        search_id   result_id   result_type   action
------------------------------------------------------------
2021-01-04  961459785   205907053   news          impression
2021-01-02  313435065   818699242   news          impression
2021-01-05  327466905   733319518   people        click
2021-01-05  327466905   393735892   news          impression
2021-01-01  806910818   127809380   other         impression
```

I need to find those search_ids that have ever had action = impression AND click. Both.

I tried using `string_agg()`:

```
select *, string_agg(action) 
from search_results
```

I have never done this before.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what role `STRING_AGG` plays here.  To answer your stated requirement, I would just use aggregation:

```sql
SELECT search_id
FROM search_results
WHERE action IN ('click', 'impression')
GROUP BY search_id
HAVING MIN(action) <> MAX(action);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select search_id 
from search_results 
where action = 'impression'
and search_id in (
    select search_id 
    from search_results 
    where action = 'click'
);
```

Comment: Corrected my answer above